# How to upgrade Impish to Jammy?

Tags: upgrade

Pretty simply I have impish and want to upgrade. I ran `do-release-upgrade` but it requires apt-get upgrade first which now fails due to the URLs being gone (`Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.`):

```
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-advantage-tools amd64 27.9~21.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core all 1:21.10.10
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 python3-distupgrade all 1:21.10.10
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
```

So how do I update so I can upgrade? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well to anyone else who encounters this I had to edit `sources.list` and manually change impish to jammy.

After that `do-release-upgrade` worked fine.

It's unfortunate this has to be done in 2022 still.

Comment: That doesn't need to be done, [Ubuntu 21.10 is EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/) meaning the repositories move, which is documented to occur **after** the EOL has been reached, hence the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades which outlines the extra step required.  If you don't want to perform the extra documented step, you can *release-upgrade* before EOL is reached.

Comment: Also note; even if you missed the warnings posted ~six weeks before the EOL (eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/) the release Ubuntu 21.10 tells you it's the 2021-October release, so adding 9 months onto that allows you to know when it reaches EOL (*the release date & announcements give you the day of the month if you need day, but month alone is a pretty good planning queue*)

Comment: Thanks man this was the first modification to sources.list that I found that actually works!..

@guiverc I strongly disagree with your line of thought... People set and forget Linux all the time for me (and many other seeing the thread) the first hint that there was anything wrong is the move of the apt repositories which happens after EOL...

Comment: For those that want a 'quick and easy' way to update their apt sources with the EOL repositories: `sudo sed -i -e 's/gb.archive.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list` :-)

(Check exactly which mirror you're using)